# auth pages not getting css in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-ui

I am beginner to laravel. I have created project. And I have run following commands to it.

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
npm install
npm run dev
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

after this command I get `Login` and `Register` menus on my welcome page.
Now my laravel welcome page loads properly. But when I click on login it shows plain html.
I serached and checked app.blade.php for links of css and js. It looks fine.
layouts/app.blade.php having following links

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Where should be the problem? Why Login and Register not getting css, when welcome page gets css? Please guide.

Comment: Can you access `/css/app.css` in your browser, does it get loaded? The Welcome page doesn't use a layout IIRC, it has styles embedded

Comment: /css/app.css showing me blank page, no errors

Comment: Please share the path of css you see in the Elements tab of developer tools.

Comment: Your .css is empty? That's strange. (Just to be sure, you accessed `http://localhost:8000/css/app.css` in your browser? Or whatever the domain is you are serving your app from) I suppose you didn't get any errors when running `npm run dev`? Browser caching problem maybe?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It should not be too hard to check which CSS paths are written to pages where it works, and those where it does not

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Step 1:

- Download **nodejs**
- Install **nodejs** in your pc

Step 2:

- then open your project root and command
- `composer require laravel/ui`
- `php artisan ui vue --auth`
- `npm install`
- `npm run dev`

After `npm` command it will generate `node_module` folder inside your project remove that folder.

`npm` command only for `.css` and `.js` file.

for help see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOYW3jqh19I&t=9s

Comment: i have already downloaded & installed nodejs and run its commands as i mentioned commands in my question. still getting problem.

Comment: I was running commands in wrong order as you can see in the question. Thats whys size of css file was zero. I guess Correct order of installing assets commands must be followed like ` composer require laravel/ui --dev, php artisan ui vue, php artisan ui vue --auth, npm install, npm run dev`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - if some pages work, and others don't, what **exactly** is changed through these two steps?

Comment: Replace vue with bootstrap for those who don't want to use vue

Comment: If `npm run dev` results in an error, or if says `Please run Mix again.` just run `npm i vue-loader` and you should be good to go

Comment: Still missing both css and js from the public folder after running all this. Must be some changes made to Laravel as I've followed official docs and tutorials and each time it doesn't work.

Answer (score 27):

The very simple solution for this problem is use the following cdn

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

instead of

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

the links I have provided are the bootstrap cdn and check that . It will work
and use

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

instead of

```
<link href="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It worked, as it should.Is there any other way though? Like, my app.js and app.css are there in public, compiled from scss with npm run dev. But the paths from app.blade.php where exactly as those above, from your answer.

Answer (score 8):

I tried following commands in laravel 8 and it works well

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install
npm run dev
npm run production
```

Answer (score 6):

Some times cache can be the issue in such case, you can run

`php artisan cache:clear` and optionally `php artisan view:clear`.

Answer (score 3):

You can download these two files from here :

1. [CSS File](https://github.com/AbdullahValley/Laravel-Vue.js-Nuxt.js/tree/master/public/css)
2. [JS File](https://github.com/AbdullahValley/Laravel-Vue.js-Nuxt.js/tree/master/public/js)

Then create **css** and **js** folders into **public** folder just put :

CSS file : **app.css** into project_folder/public/css/

JS file : **app.js**  into project_folder/public/js/

Its work for me. I think it will also work for you. Thanks.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - if some pages work, and others don't, what exactly is changed through these two steps?

Comment: app.css is also empty!, I filled it with bootstrap.min.css  and now working Thank You for the answer

Answer (score 3):

### You need to run the below commands for laravel 7.x.

**Solution**

First go to your project root folder  C:\Whatever\Your_project_name>

```
      composer require laravel/ui
```

Try any of the below command according to your front-end framework.

```
      php artisan ui vue --auth
      php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
      php artisan ui react --auth
```

At the end don't forget to run

```
      npm install
```

If your User Interface is not working properly try below command.

```
      npm run production
```

---

If the above commands don't work for you.

---

**Reason**: The error is because there is no css code in the public/css/app.css when you have executed all the commands but still there would be no code in that folder.

Take the file or code from here https://github.com/sabaoonbedar/Css-File-For-Laravel-Developers/tree/master  and place it in your project public/css/app.css **OR** create similar folders if don't exists.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was simply the `npm run dev` command.
In my ubuntu 19.10, it has to run with sudo

Comment: running DEV I get:
`[webpack-cli] /home/stephen/Websites/CNO/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:18
    static _primary = null;`
and a bunch of errors. Any ideas why or how to resolve this - I'm stuck

Comment: @Hondaman900 If you still have this issue you should open a stackoverflow request, from the error code you said I don't know what it could be, maybe simply remove node_modules and do a fresh npm i.

Answer (score 2):

I tried following commands in laravel 8 and it works well, you can also give it a try.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install
npm run dev
npm run production
```

Comment: I fixed the problem with that code:
`npm run production`

Thank you @ataur-rahman

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your node.js version was outdated. Just update the Node.js and start from the beginning by installing the laravel ui and so on.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install
npm run dev
```

Hope it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You must compile packages use `npm run watch` command. after that you can run `npm run dev`

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the cache on your browser. To confirm that go into incognito mode and try your URL again. If it works then that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

run

1. `npm install`
2. `npm run dev`
3. `npm run watch` for continues compiling the code

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue CSS & js works with CDN links but not with default CSS. so there was files no CSS code in the public/css/app.css and js files so I copy and paste the code and files in the public directory from my another laravel directory and now that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below commands in your Laravel project.

```
composer require laravel/ui 
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem while implementing the `composer require laravel/ui` in laravel version 7 but I fixed it by following the below steps.

First :

- Download **nodejs**
- Install **nodejs** in your pc

Second : run this command

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Once the `laravel/ui` package has been installed, you may install the frontend scaffolding using the ui Artisan command:

```
// Generate basic scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui react

// Generate login / registration scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

To generate `node_module` folder inside your project run the below command

```
npm install
```

Once the dependencies have been installed using npm install, you can compile your SASS files to plain CSS using Laravel Mix. The npm run dev command will process the instructions in your webpack.mix.js file. Typically, your compiled CSS will be placed in the public/css directory:

```
npm run dev
```

some time you may need to run this command `npm audit fix` or `npm audit fix --force` to fix some packages if they required to be.

Maybe some time by running this command `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` it will show you an error like below.

> ```
> @ dev C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth
>  npm run development 
> @ development C:\xampp\htdocs\Auth
> mix
>         Additional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.
>  
>         Finished. Please run Mix again.
>  
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
> ```

jus run the `npm run watch` again it will start `Mix █████████████████████████ emitting (95%)` after the success the build will be succeeded too.

Answer (score 0):

This command working in my machine command.

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   composer require laravel/ui

   php artisan ui vue
   npm install
   npm run dev

   php artisan ui vue --auth
   npm install
   npm run dev
```

You will have to call npm install and npm run dev for both scaffolding

Answer (score 0):

after install every thing try this

```
npm update vue-loader
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just downloaded the **latest version of nodejs** and install it. After, just type **npm run dev**. And refresh your browser and good to go!! Cheers!!

Comment: Can you explain why you should do something like this?

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz it's because of version compatibility. So you need to update your nodejs version to latest version

Answer (score 0):

you can use the styles and the script like this :

Style :

```
 <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS :

```
 <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Run the command:

```
npm uninstall popper.js && npm i @popperjs/core
```

to remove the deprecated package and install their new Popper v2.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - if some pages work, and others don't, what exactly is changed through this?

Answer (score -1):

Public your CSS. I mean keep your CSS file in the public directory of your project.
Your css file should be here at: yourprojectname\public\css\app.css