# Laravel front end scafolding doesen't works

Tags: php, laravel

When I enter `composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "8.0"` it creates the blog with Laravel 8. After that I create front end scaffolding with `composer require laravel/ui:^3.0` and `php artisan ui vue --auth`. After that I `npm install && npm run dev`. And it doesn't look how it should look. (Picture 1)

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Did you miss step #2? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63868520/296555

Comment: Any updates here? Looks like your CSS isn't loading. Seeing 404 or other error codes in your browser console? FYI, Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111841/auth-pages-not-getting-css-in-laravel.