# login and regristration form not appearing like it should

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have done in terminal

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel Push "8.0"
cd Push 
composer require laravel/ui
```

Then change package.json file to :
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/package.json#L12

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install --save-dev cross-env
npm install vue 
npm install vue-loader
npm install vue-template-compiler
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

in webpack.mix.js do [How to fix the error "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607153/how-to-fix-the-error-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-typ)

```
npm install&&npm run dev
```

And so does my login and registration not appear right what to do different.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P5ZR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpmqD.png)

It should be like picture 1

Comment: I think css is not loading on login page, Please try to follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58111841/auth-pages-not-getting-css-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

you should check your browser console/network errors then you can fix them. Can you also share your browser console/network errors in the question?

Comment: This should be a comment on the question instead of an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please create css file in directorty patch public->css->loginForm.css and copy past login form css.Then call login_form.blade.php top use it

```
<link href="/css/loginForm.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: CSS/styles should work out of the box. Just creating a CSS file and linking it will not help. What contents should the file have?

Comment: dindn't see that